# "Dot initialization syntax" in C

Tags: c, struct

I came across some C code with an unusual structure initialization syntax.

```
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr = {
    .tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx,
    .rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx,
    .len = ARRAY_SIZE(tx),
    .delay_usecs = delay,
    .speed_hz = speed,
    .bits_per_word = bits,
};
```

First off, I have no idea what this is called. What is this known as? Perhaps "dot initialisation syntax" as I suggested in the question title? I have not encountered this before so I don't know how to describe it.

Secondly, this is valid C code as it compiles, however what dialect of C is this and when was it introduced? (Was it new in C11?)

Thirdly, if some members of the struct are omitted, are those members initialized to zero. If not, is there a way to initialize the struct such that omitted members are zero.

(For example `spi_ios_transfer` also contains a field `cs-change` which has been omitted here.)

Finally is this permitted also in C++, and does it work with C++ classes?

Comment: This is a "designated initializer": https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization

Comment: This is one of *designator*. [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) (C99) has that (6.7.8 Initialization), but [C89](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.5.7) doesn't seem having that.

Answer (score 2):

> First off, I have no idea what this is called.

Designated initializer

> Secondly, this is valid C code as it compiles, however what dialect of C is this and when was it introduced? (Was it new in C11?)

C99 and later

> Thirdly, if some members of the struct are omitted, are those members initialized to zero.

Yes

> Finally is this permitted also in C++, and does it work with C++ classes?

It was introduced in C++20